# Is there a pre coding stage forum?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

SO frowns on algorithm/analysis/design advice questions which are pre coding stage.
Is there a low noise forum available to air these discussions ?

Comment: Maybe try chat?

Comment: What makes you think that *SO frowns on algorithm/analysis/design advice questions which are pre coding stage* [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314077/algorithm-for-exclusion-of-numbers) got 7 up-votes and was asked 10 hours ago

Comment: [programmers.se] is for "whiteboard problems" but SO might also be appropriate depending

Comment: SO frowns on the term _forum._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stack Overflow *does* frown on vaguely stated, airy or too open questions along the lines of *"What's the easiest way to <do something genuinely hard>?"* or *"What data structure should I used to <some imprecise problem specification>?"*

Step one is to *not* write that kind of question.

Give your audience some specifics. How big is the data set? Is this a one-off or production? What means are you considering to solve the problem?